# Activity stack behavior when activity is started from widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-task

I have two avtivities. Let's call them `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. ActivityA is marked `singleTask` in manifest file. 
I can start `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` using simple `startActivity` call (no `Intent` flags used). Also I can start `ActivityC` from `ActivityA` and start `ActivityB` from it (also using "simple" `Intents`).

`ActivityB` has a button which performs this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this,
                ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

I also have a widget which can start `ActivityA` using this code:

```
Intent aIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
aIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                aIntent, 0);
```

And also it can start `ActivityB` from grid items:

```
Intent bIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
PendingIntent bPendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
        .addNextIntent(aIntent).addNextIntent(bIntent )
        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

If I start `ActivityA` from launcher, start `ActivityB` from it (or `ActivityA`->`ActivityC`->`ActivityB`) - I can move back to `ActyvityA` (or `ActivityC`) using back button or button in `ActivityB` (described above) and `ActivityA` is not recreated.
That's OK.

The problem is that if I start `ActivityB` from widget and use back button or button in `ActivityB` (described above) `ActivityA` is recreated and becomes single instance in stack.

I want to be able to manage those two activities the way `ActivityA` is always the root one and NOT RECREATED if it is already running.

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry, ActivityA call from widget works fine with code above. The problem is only with launching ActivityB as part of TaskStack which includes ActivityA. In my manifest only ActivityA marked as "singleTask". Other activities have all task related options unchaged (default).

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. I deleted my answer and created a new one. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this using `TaskStackBuilder`. You can avoid using `TaskStackBuilder` if you can figure out a way to making sure that `ActivityB` is never launched into a task unless `ActivityA` is already there. In this way, when `ActivityB` returns to `ActivityA`, the instance of `ActivityA` will not get recreated.

To solve this problem, instead of launching `ActivityB` directly from the widget, you should launch `ActivityA` and pass an extra that tells `ActivityA` that you want it to launch `ActivityB`:

```
Intent bIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
bIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
bIntent.putExtra("launchActivityB", true);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            bIntent, 0);
```

In both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` of `ActivityA`, check for the presence of the extra and if it is there you should launch `ActivityB` immediately.